# Servlet is dowloanded as a file, instead of presenting HTML on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a lot of experience in servlets and tomcat, but today was the second time I encountered something strange: after playing around with the servlet doGet logic, when I accessed the servlet it started download the file (instead of execute the logic!).
It happens in all browsers, and it happens also when I deploy the webapp on different configuration of the tomcat (but still, on eclipse. maybe the bug is in the tomcat eclipse plugin?)

The logic I wrote is not something that might be related to the content type. When I tried to change the content type - it still consider the servlet as a file, and tried to download it.

Does someone know this bug?

EDIT:
Here are the examples-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import db.StoreItems;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Controller
 */
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String supportMail ;
    int hitCounter =0;
    String counter ;
    StoreItems store;

    public Controller() {
        super();

    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {

    supportMail = getInitParameter("email");
    store = new StoreItems();
    counter = getInitParameter("hitCounter");
    hitCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter);


}

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(hitCounter);
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

The web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>OnlineStore</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Controller</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>
        </description>
        <param-name>email</param-name>
        <param-value>support@online.store</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>hitCounter</param-name>
        <param-value>7</param-value>
    </init-param>
        </servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Varsions: Tomcat 7, eclipse indigo, java 6, servlet api 2.4.
I tried to change eclipse workspace, and it still did not work.

Comment: Have you tried check headers in HTTP response? With `curl -v your-url.com` if you use linux for example.

Comment: Step 1: to prove to yourself that the bug is not in the Eclipse plugin (it's not likely), package up the WAR and deploy on a dedicated Tomcat instance. Step 2: post your `web.xml` code here, along with the verion of Tomcan that you're running, because without it there's not much that anybody can do to help you.

Comment: It would help if you cut down the servlet's code to the smallest possible piece which still reproduces this problem and post it and also if you show the request URL and the HTTP response headers which the browser retrieved when requesting the servlet's URL.

Comment: This is *not* "the smallest possible piece which still reproduces the problem". Does the problem disappear if you remove `supportMail` property? No? Leave it away and continue cutting down.

Comment: Are you sure its not because of your content type. I could see you are setting the content type of your response to plain text, and thats why its downloading a file when you try to access the servlet from browser. Is my understanding correct. ?

Answer (score 3):

Set response as text.html

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

I am sure it will resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
response.getWriter().write(hitCounter).flush();
```

should show you a result

Answer (score 0):

What is downloaded? The servlet source code? You have to compile the code to a .class file and put it in WEB-INF/classes. Eclipse should do that automatically if you put your java file in a Java Source folder.

Answer (score 0):

Btw if you return online text and that's exactly what your servlet does with the content type text/plain, you should rather use for example jquery ajax to parse the text result and render it into the html or jsp from which the request is issued.

If you use the content type text/html you should see the result but then at least wrap it into the minimum html tags  your value  in your servlet.

Regards
s